# Why I am getting error 'Server rejected the 1 private key' error on setting up ssh-slave docker image

Tags: docker, jenkins, ssh, containers, jenkins-agent

I am running both jenkins master and slave as docker containers by using jenkins/jenkins:lts and jenkins/ssh-slave image on Ubuntu. Following are the steps:

- Ran `ssh-keygen` inside the jenkins-master container(`docker exec -it container_id bash`) to generate the ssh keys
- Added the generated public key to authorized_keys file inside ssh-slave container using dockerfile
- Added private key inside Jenkins credentials as per this [link](https://devopscube.com/setup-slaves-on-jenkins-2/)

I have looked at many questions related to this issue on stackoverflow but I am stuck with following error:

*[02/08/19 20:31:06] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to ###.##.#.#:22.
[02/08/19 20:31:06] [SSH] SSH host key matches key in Known Hosts file. Connection will be allowed.
**ERROR: Server rejected the 1 private key(s) for jenkins (credentialId:worker-ssh/method:publickey)
[02/08/19 20:31:06] [SSH] Authentication failed.
Authentication failed.**
[02/08/19 20:31:06] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
[02/08/19 20:31:06] [SSH] Connection closed.*

**Slave Template in Jenkins:**

**Name**: jenkins-worker

**Usage**: Use this node as much as possible

**Launch method**: Launch agent via SSH

**Hostname**: my ip extracted from ifconfig

**Host key verification startegy**: known hosts file verification strategy (.ssh/known_hosts contains entry for host ip provided)

Dockerfile for ssh-slave

```
    #Docker version 18.09.1
    FROM jenkins/ssh-slave
    COPY /.ssh/id_rsa.pub /.ssh/authorized_keys
    RUN chmod 744 /.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: Thank you. I looked at stack exchange but i could not find tags related to my question. I have updated my question with shorter description.